# How to instantiate and call methods dynamically of a class member in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic

I have an issue with Java Reflection. Here's my code very much simplified.

Let's say we have this class :

```
public class MyClassA {
    private MyClassB myPropertyB_1;
    private MyClassB myPropertyB_2;

    ...
}
```

And this class (which is used as a property for MyClassA :

```
public class MyClassB {

    private int myProperty;

    public MyClassB(){
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to use Java Reflection to do something like this, in `MyClassA` :

```
    public void methodThatUsesReflectionOnProperty(int id){
        // 1. Get the field using id
        // 2. Instantiate this field dynamically (i.e. new MyClassB() )
        // 3. Invoke some methods on this field dynamically (setters, addlisteners...)
}
```

How could I do this ?

Comment: Is it possible you can consider a redesign that does not require you to use reflection? It seems ugly to require this (if you have full control over the classes). For instance, can you maintain a list of properties in `MyClassA` and provide getter setter methods to allow other classes to access and modify them?

Comment: Actually I'm developping on Android and trying to generate Forms automatically, with a list of Field, and I considered refactoring everything, but it seemed not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a field using:

```
classObject.getDeclaredField(String fieldName);
```

You can get a method using:

```
classObject.getDeclaredMethod(String methodName, Class<?> ... parameterTypes);
```

And you can instantiate it with `newInstance()` of course, if there is a default constructor.

For instance:

```
ClassA aObj = new ClassA();

// field access
Field field = ClassA.class.getDeclaredField("objectB");
Object bObj = field.getType().newInstance();
field.setAccessible(true); // as it is private it needs to be accessible first
field.set(aObj, bObj); // set bObj into field from aObj

// invoking method
Method method = bObj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("methodB", String.class);
method.invoke(bObj, "reflection test!");
```

This will print:

```
B wrote: reflection test!
```

Comment: Yes, but how to do for example : `myPropertyB_1 = new MyPropertyB()` with reflection ? Because  `getDeclaredField(String fieldName)` returns a Field and not a MyPropertyB.

Comment: I didn't know how to use the Field, with the getType().newInstance(), and then set(...). Hard to guess ^^

Comment: And how to get a constructor that has parameters. I have to do ...newInstance(this);

Answer (score 0):

So if i get you right you want to get the field myPropertyB_1 in case you call the methodThatUsesReflectionOnProperty with '1' for id?

In this case just work with a Map instead of reflection. This could look like:

```
public class MyClassA {
   private Map<Integer,MyClassB> myProperty;

   public void initMethod(Integer i) {
       if(this.myProperty.get(i)!=null)return;
       MyClassB myClassB = new MyClassB();
       this.myProperty.set(i, myClassB);
   }
}
```

Comment: In fact I am using a lot of Maps and would like to refactor with Reflection ^^

Comment: but why is that? as @Duncan Jones said the reflection approach seems to be ugly ;)